# Download file from SharePoint using Python - Response 200 but output a html with title ERROR

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint

The response is 200 - OK, but the output is a html that has title error.

Do you know what might be the reason and how to solve it?

I tried to download files from Sharepoint using this code:

```
url='https://<tenant>/sites/sitesname/folder/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id='CLIENT_ID', client_secret='CLIENTSECRET')
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)

response = File.open_binary(ctx, "/folder/filename.docx")
print(response)
with open("./TEST.docx", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)

HTML OUTPUT:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr" class="ms-isBot"> <head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" /><title>       Error  </title><link id="CssLink-ef104b8cce1e4964a50c5c1f63c97578" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css?rev=%2BOT110kIG4UZqRwn1SzXow%3D%3DTAG1379"/> <link id="CssLink-fbffc9bfd4a74b699c439f39d22d8f4e" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/error.css?rev=tF7fyfzbaQzNoASoSDlV4A%3D%3DTAG1379"/> <style id="SPThemeHideForms" type="text/css">body {opacity:0 !important}</style><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[   var _initGlobalSnapShot = {};try {    if (Object.keys(_initGlobalSnapShot).length == 0) {       for (var memberIndex in window) {          if (Boolean(memberIndex)) {              _initGlobalSnapShot[memberIndex] = 1;         }      }   }} catch (ex) {}; // ]]> </script>
```

Comment: I still cannot resolve it. I am looking into the permission, however, it should not be the case because we use app-only authentication and the app have full-control permissions

Answer (score 0):

The URL of a SharePoint does not the serve the file immediately most of the time, it serve an Online Word/Excel/PowerPoint Editor or a PDF viewer, which is probably the output you retrieve.

I'd advise to leverage the SharePoint Rest API and use its endpoints to get what you want:

`<site-url>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file-server-relative-url>')/$value`

should give you what you want

Comment: How do I convert to that endpoints?

Comment: my endpoint is as follow: "/sites/ITIO/individual/Forms/AllItems.aspx/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='Nga/fddfs.jfif')/%5C$value"

Comment: The problem is I cannot delete the /Forms/AllItems.aspx part because if not including that, I cannot get authentication

Comment: I don't know the framework you're using, but you should acquire a token using only the site collection url, without the `/folder/Forms/AllItems.aspx` part, as a token is scoped by site collection

Comment: I can get the token and passed through authentication if use username and password, but when I pass the path to the fil in File.open_binary(), it said the the file <path to file> does not exist.

Comment: Again, I don't know what the class `File` and the method `open_file` do, so I really can't say what it's doing, or why it's failing. I've given you the Rest API URL, if you have an access token, you can call it directly. Maybe someone with the knowledge of your Python library will help you